# Swapping contract tokens to ETH on all Uniswap buys fails, sells work

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Consider this code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

contract TaxToken is ERC20, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

    uint8 private constant _decimals = 18;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable _router;
    address public immutable _weth9;
    address public immutable _pair;
    bool public canClaim = false;
    mapping(address => bool) public isExcludedFromFee; // mapping of all addresses excluded from taxes     

    constructor() payable ERC20("testToken", "TEST") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000000000 * 10 ** 18);
        _router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
        _weth9 = _router.WETH();
        _pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_router.factory()).createPair(address(this), _weth9);
        isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;        
    }

    function mint(uint256 amount, address to) external onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }  

    function enableClaim() public virtual {
        canClaim = true;
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override {
        require(amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");        
        require(from != address(0));
        require(from != to);

        uint256 _finalTax = 0;
        
        if(isExcludedFromFee[to] || isExcludedFromFee[from]) super._transfer(from, to, amount);              
        
        else {                        

            // IF ITS A BUY
            if (from == _pair) {
                if (!canClaim) _finalTax = (amount * 10 / 100);
            }

            // IF ITS A SELL
            else if (to == _pair) _finalTax = (amount * 10 / 100);                                  

            if(_finalTax > 0) {
                super._transfer(from, address(this), _finalTax);                                     
            }

            super._transfer(from, to, amount - _finalTax);                                     

            if (canClaim && balanceOf(address(this)) > 0) {
                _swapTokensForETH(balanceOf(address(this)));
            }            
                     
        }
    }

    function _swapTokensForETH(uint256 amount_) internal {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = _weth9;
        _approve(address(this), address(_router), amount_);
        _router.swapExactTokensForETH(
            amount_,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),            
            block.timestamp
        );
    }   


    receive() external payable {} // allow the contract to recieve ETH
   
}
```

This is reduced code from a larger contract, isolating the specific issue I keep facing. So I am aware there may be various security checks missing etc and the token mechanics perhaps don't make sense, but I am just trying to widdle it down to the problem parts.

Essentially what this contract should do is:

1. Apply a 10% tax on all buys and sell via Uni and deposit those tokens into the contract.
2. Once `canClaim` is called and enabled; remove the tax from buys, for each buy check whether there is a token balance greater than 0 in the contract, if there is then swap those tokens to ETH and deposit that ETH to the contract via the `_swapTokensForETH` function

The tax adjustment works, but once `canClaim` is enabled and therefore the `_swapTokensForETH` function triggers on buys, all buys fail.

**What I have tried to debug this:**

- I have tried switching the logic to trigger the `_swapTokensForETH` function on *sells* instead and that works fine.
- I have tried playing with the slippage on the failing buys, all the way up to 49%.
- I have tried whole numbers and decimals in the swap fields for the buy.
- I have tried using `swapexacttokensforethsupportingfeeontransfertokens` instead
- I have tried transferring large numbers of the native token to the contract first to make sure there is not a problem swapping due to it trying to swap small amounts. And in any case, if that was the issue then it would not work on sells either, but it does.

Can anyone help identify what I am missing here? Thanks.